# Combine multiple filter() predicates in Underscore / Ramda / Functional languages / Libraries

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, functional-programming, underscore.js

For a list of data I want to filter it using several predicates and then do an operation on each filter.

Eg. if my data is:

```
var people = [
    {name: 'Sachin',    profession: 'doctor',   cases: 12},
    {name: 'Djokovic',  profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 14},
    {name: 'Paes',      profession: 'doctor',   cases: 36},
    {name: 'Jordan',    profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 78},
    {name: 'Williams',  profession: 'doctor',   cases: 30},
    {name: 'Nehwal',    profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 75}
]
```

I want to convert it to:

```
var peopleWithoutCases = [
    {name: 'Sachin',    profession: 'doctor',   patients:   12, cases: 12},
    {name: 'Djokovic',  profession: 'lawyer',   courtcases: 14, cases: 14},
    {name: 'Paes',      profession: 'doctor',   patients:   36, cases: 36},
    {name: 'Jordan',    profession: 'lawyer',   courtcases: 78, cases: 78},
    {name: 'Williams',  profession: 'doctor',   patients:   30, cases: 30},
    {name: 'Nehwal',    profession: 'lawyer',   courtcases: 75, cases: 75}
]
```

Is there an elegant functional approach like this??

```
    people
    .filter (person => person.profession == 'doctor')
    .map    (person => {
                person.patients = person.cases
                return person;
            })
    .filter (person => person.profession == 'lawyer')
    .map    (person => {
                person.courtcases = person.cases
                return person;
            })
```

Problem is the first `map` returns an array where there are only `doctor`s. So the second `filter` returns `[]`.

I know I can do this:

```
_.union(
    people
        .filter (person => person.profession == 'doctor')
        .map    (person => {
                    person.patients = person.cases
                    return person;
                }),
    people
        .filter (person => person.profession == 'lawyer')
        .map    (person => {
                    person.courtcases = person.cases
                    return person;
                })
)
```

*Please correct me if I'm wrong* but, this takes a *multi pass* approach to the problem which is *inefficient* in my opinion as the array list grows and the number of predicates grow.

Its quite easy to write this with an imperative approach. A single `for` loop with multiple `if` statements. Efficient but not *elegant* :)

Please suggest the best approach using Functional javascript like Underscore, LoDash or the Excellent RamdaJS library. How's it done in pure functional languages?

Note:

1. Array order is not important in this case.
2. Please don't take the example literally and suggest alternate solutions, I want a **general** solution for filtering and mapping lists fir multiple predicates.

Comment: maybe you should have an array of filters that you call on each items in one loop .

Comment: @Anonymous0day Yeah i thought of that but then the `map` also has to be in that array. If the operation is more camplex than just a `map` then that's a really big / non functional array we have there!

Comment: Not really don't forget you can augment / modify the `person` from the filter function !

Comment: This isn't really filtering but rather conditional augmentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62409101/1166087 (and my answer in there) for a discussion of actual multi-predicate filtering in Underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Try like that :

```js
var el = document.getElementById('dbg');
var $l = function( val ){
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + '<div class="line"><pre>' + val + '</pre></div>';
}



var people = [
    {name: 'Sachin',    profession: 'doctor',   cases: 12},
    {name: 'Djokovic',  profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 14},
    {name: 'Paes',      profession: 'doctor',   cases: 36},
    {name: 'Jordan',    profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 78},
    {name: 'Williams',  profession: 'doctor',   cases: 30},
    {name: 'Nehwal',    profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 75},
    {name: 'Nawak',     profession: 'developper',   cases: 750}
]

var modifiers = {
  'doctor' : function(  ){ this.patients =this.cases ; return this} , 
  'lawyer' : function(  ){ this.courtcases = this.cases; return this; } , 
  'developper' : function(  ){ this.program = this.cases; return this; } , 
}
var result = people.map(function( p){
      modifiers[p.profession].call( p );
      return p;
    })
console.dir(result);
$l( JSON.stringify( result , null , ' ' ) );
```

```css
.line {
  border : solid 1px #AAA;
  padding : 3px;
  margin : 3px;
  }
```

```html
<div id='dbg'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the objects, clone the object (using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) or [`_.extend()`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)) to prevent changing the original, and apply the filters using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var people = [{"name":"Sachin","profession":"doctor","cases":12},{"name":"Djokovic","profession":"lawyer","cases":14},{"name":"Paes","profession":"doctor","cases":36},{"name":"Jordan","profession":"lawyer","cases":78},{"name":"Williams","profession":"doctor","cases":30},{"name":"Nehwal","profession":"lawyer","cases":75}];

var propsMap = {
  'doctor': 'patients',
  'lawyer': 'courtcases'
};

var filters = [
  function cases2Prof(person) {
    person[propsMap[person.profession]] = person.cases;

    return person;
  },

  function removeCases(person) {
    delete person.case;
    return person;
  }
];

var result = applyFilters(people, filters);

function applyFilters(array, filters) {
  return array.map(function(item) {
    var cloned = Object.assign({}, item); // clone the object to prevent mutating the original

    // run all filters on the object
    return filters.reduce(function(object, filter) {
      return filter(cloned);
    }, cloned);
  });
}

console.table(result);

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, ' ');
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Comment: This is a good solution! But, what if my `filter` function is not a simple property filter?

Comment: I've transformed the answer to a more generic one (missed the request in the question).

Answer (score 1):

requirement for 2 filter operations done in parallel, is directing to use reduce here, instead of filter.

using lodash-fp specifically to use flow functional style, else normal lodash/underscore can be used.

```js
   

 var people = [
    {name: 'Sachin', profession: 'doctor', cases: 12},
    {name: 'Djokovic', profession: 'lawyer', cases: 14},
    {name: 'Paes', profession: 'doctor', cases: 36},
    {name: 'Jordan', profession: 'lawyer', cases: 78},
    {name: 'Williams', profession: 'doctor', cases: 30},
    {name: 'Nehwal', profession: 'lawyer', cases: 75},
    {name: 'Nawak', profession: 'developper', cases: 750}
]

var mapper = {"doctor": "patients", "lawyer": "courtcases"};

var process = _.flow(_.reduce((r, e, i) => [...r, mapper[e.profession] && {
    ...e,
    [mapper[e.profession]]: e.cases
}], []), _.compact);

console.log(process(people))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-fp/0.10.4/lodash-fp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is my solution. Tell me whatcha think!

I think this solution is elegant and I believe it's linear time too.
You probably don't need to use Ramda.js like I did though.

```js
var people = [
    {name: 'Sachin',    profession: 'doctor',   cases: 12},
    {name: 'Djokovic',  profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 14},
    {name: 'Paes',      profession: 'doctor',   cases: 36},
    {name: 'Jordan',    profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 78},
    {name: 'Williams',  profession: 'doctor',   cases: 30},
    {name: 'Nehwal',    profession: 'lawyer',   cases: 75}
]

const professionToCaseType = {
  doctor: 'patients', 
  lawyer: 'courtcases',
}

const transformPerson = (person) => 
    R.assoc(professionToCaseType[person.profession], person.cases, person)

const transformPeople = 
    R.map(transformPerson)

console.log(transformPeople(people))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution using Underscore is as follows.

```js
var caseType = {
    doctor: 'patients',
    lawyer: 'courtcases',
};

var peopleWithoutCases = _.map(people, person => _.extend({
    [caseType[person.profession]]: person.cases,
}, person);
```

Note that `peopleWithoutCases` is a bit of a misnomer, because the `cases` properties are still included in the result. If you actually want to leave them out, this is easy to fix:

```js
var caseType = {
    doctor: 'patients',
    lawyer: 'courtcases',
};

var peopleWithoutCases = _.map(people, person => _.extend({
    [caseType[person.profession]]: person.cases,
}, _.omit(person, 'cases'));
```